# CNN sudden drop in accuracy after steady increase over ~24 epochs

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I'm attempting to create a CNN to classify emotions based on facial expressions from an image. I'm using [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/challenges-in-representation-learning-facial-expression-recognition-challenge/data?select=test.csv) I found on Kaggle, in csv format with each row having grayscale image data and emotion. It has ~30,000 data points randomly split into 80% training, 10% validation and 10% testing.

While adjusting settings and structure of my CNN I've experienced at least one of these problems at a time.

- CNN only (or mainly) predicting one or two outputs.
- Validation Accuracy that does not change at all
- Accuracy fluctuating around equivalent to random guessing (16.66%) +/- 10%
- Constant accuracy and loss for both training and data

I've tried changing learning rate, optimizer, batch size, number of filters, epochs. I've used a different data set and tried class weights for slight imbalance as well as varying numbers of hidden layers and complexities.
I've also tried training on one sample but got [this for accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX82c.png) and [this for loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YHGg.png).

The following graphs are for the configuration currently in the code, though changing what I've listed above just results in any of the problems I mentioned.

[Train/Val Accuracy during training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaPxs.png)

[Train/Vall Loss during training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmv9n.png)

I suspected it may be due to labels being mismatched with data, so I manually check whether labels and images matched in train_set, which they did.
However using the following code to check them in all_sets (after conversion) gave several mismatched data samples out of 16.

```
for num, row in enumerate(all_sets[0]):
  if num < 16:
    newimage = tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(row)
    newimage.save("filename.png")  # takes type from filename extension 
    display(Image('filename.png'))
    print(classes[all_labels[0][num]])
    !rm -rf filename.png
```

Conversion code in question:

```
tempSets = [train_set, test_set, val_set] #store all sets in list to iterate through

#panda reads image from CSV as a string rather than an array of floats. 
#convert from panda dataframe to numpy array, as easier to feed into image augmentation
set_sizes = [train_set.shape[0] , test_set.shape[0], val_set.shape[0]] #Array storing number of records for each set
all_sets = [np.empty([set_sizes[0], 48,48,1], dtype=float), # train
            np.empty([set_sizes[1], 48,48,1], dtype=float), # test
            np.empty([set_sizes[2], 48,48,1], dtype=float)] # validate

all_labels = [np.empty(set_sizes[0], dtype=int), # train
            np.empty(set_sizes[1], dtype=int), # test
            np.empty(set_sizes[2], dtype=int)] # validate

for count, val in enumerate(tempSets): # for each set
  for num, row in enumerate(val.itertuples()): #each row in a set, store as a tuple and keep index num
    num_str_list = row._2.split() # split long string into array of string seperated by whitespaces (_2 is emotion, for some reason it renames itself)
    for convertI in range(len(num_str_list)): # for each element in string array
      num_str_list[convertI] = float(num_str_list[convertI]) #convert to float and store in new (1d) array
    for xPixel in range(48): 
      for yPixel in range(48):
        #match indexes to map 1d array contents into 2d
        all_sets[count][num, xPixel, yPixel, 0] = num_str_list[xPixel*48 + yPixel] 
    all_labels[count][num] = data['emotion'][num] #assign labels with matching index
```

I'm afraid I'm lost as to where the issue is, as I can't find problems in my conversion or in displaying the images. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

My full code:

```
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=False)
driveContent='/content/drive/My Drive/EmotionClassification'

#Set base_dir as current working directory
base_dir = os.getcwd()

#Check whether training data is present in current working directory
dataSetIsInColab = False
for fname in os.listdir(base_dir): #get all names in current directory
  if fname == 'icml_face_data.csv':
    dataSetIsInColab = True

if dataSetIsInColab == False:
  #dataset.zip is a zip file containing a CSV file which holds the dataset. 
  zip_path = os.path.join(driveContent,'dataset.zip') #grab content from drive
  !cp "{zip_path}" .  #Copy zip file to current working directory
  !unzip -q dataset.zip  # Unzip (-q prevents printing all files)
  !rm dataset.zip #Remove zip file since we now have unzipped data

data = panda.read_csv('icml_face_data.csv') # import data as panda dataframe object
data.pop(' Usage') #remove unnecessary column
data.rename(columns={" pixels":"pixels"}) # remove space from column name as it can cause issues
data[data['emotion']!=1] #remove disgust emotion due to large imbalance
data.loc[data['emotion'] > 1, 'emotion'] = data['emotion'] - 1 #shift emotion values to fill disgust slot

classes = ['anger', 'fear', 'happiness', 'sadness', 'surprise', 'neutral']

#Use panda dataframe methods to randomly split dataset
train_set = data.sample(frac=0.8) # Train set is 80%
temp_set = data.drop(train_set.index) # Temp set is 20%
test_set = temp_set.sample(frac=0.5) #Test set is half of 20%
val_set = temp_set.drop(test_set.index) #Val set is the other half of 20%

#train_set.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
#test_set.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
#val_set.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

tempSets = [train_set, test_set, val_set] #store all sets in list to iterate through

#panda reads image from CSV as a string rather than an array of floats. 
#convert from panda dataframe to numpy array, as easier to feed into image augmentation
set_sizes = [train_set.shape[0] , test_set.shape[0], val_set.shape[0]] #Array storing number of records for each set
all_sets = [np.empty([set_sizes[0], 48,48,1], dtype=float), # train
            np.empty([set_sizes[1], 48,48,1], dtype=float), # test
            np.empty([set_sizes[2], 48,48,1], dtype=float)] # validate

all_labels = [np.empty(set_sizes[0], dtype=int), # train
            np.empty(set_sizes[1], dtype=int), # test
            np.empty(set_sizes[2], dtype=int)] # validate

for count, val in enumerate(tempSets): # for each set
  for num, row in enumerate(val.itertuples()): #each row in a set, store as a tuple and keep index num
    num_str_list = row._2.split() # split long string into array of string seperated by whitespaces (_2 is emotion, for some reason it renames itself)
    for convertI in range(len(num_str_list)): # for each element in string array
      num_str_list[convertI] = float(num_str_list[convertI]) #convert to float and store in new (1d) array
    for xPixel in range(48): 
      for yPixel in range(48):
        #match indexes to map 1d array contents into 2d
        all_sets[count][num, xPixel, yPixel, 0] = num_str_list[xPixel*48 + yPixel] 
    all_labels[count][num] = data['emotion'][num] #assign labels with matching index

#Check to use GPU if possible
gpu_name = tensorflow.test.gpu_device_name()
if gpu_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  print('GPU device not found')
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(gpu_name))

 #SET UP IMAGE AUGMENTATION AND INPUT
imgShape=(48,48,1) # input image dimensions (greyscale)
batchSize = 64

#this datagen is applied to training sets
dataGen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=45,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip = True)

# Set up data generator batches, shapes and class modes
trainingDataGen = dataGen.flow(
                    x=all_sets[0], 
                    y=tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(all_labels[0]),
                    batch_size=batchSize)

testGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).flow(
                    x=all_sets[1],
                    y=tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(all_labels[1]))

validGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).flow(
                    x=all_sets[2],
                    y=tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(all_labels[2]),
                    batch_size=batchSize)

# BUILD THE MODEL
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape = imgShape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax')) 

model.summary() # Show the structure of the network

opt = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.0001) # initialise optimizer
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy']) 

weights = sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(all_labels[0]), all_labels[0]) # use class weights for imbalanced classes
weights = {i : weights[i] for i in range(6)}

history = model.fit(
    trainingDataGen,
    batch_size = batchSize,
    epochs = 32,
    class_weight = weights,
    validation_data = validGen
)
```

EDIT: I found the issue in my conversion, I was assigning labels based on the unsplit data instead of each split set individually.

From all_labels[count][num] = data['emotion'][num] to

all_labels[count][num] = row.emotion

Labels are matching now. Training accuracy/loss steadily improves, but validation [accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn8A9.png) and [loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAn2w.png) are fluctuating a lot. I'm going to do some more tweaking, but is this something I should worry about?

EDIT 2: Made title more fitting
So I left it training for more epochs, and here are the results.
[accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfDTw.png) and [loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M52uj.png).
Peaking at 35% isn't ideal

EDIT 3: It's back to fluctuating wildly.
[accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Bb1.png) and [loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmIWu.png).
I used some code to test predictions of my network after training. Here are results;

```
Total tests performed:  4068
Total accuracy:  0.17649950835791545

anger : {'Successes': 0, 'Occured': 567} Accuracy:  0.0
fear : {'Successes': 0, 'Occured': 633} Accuracy:  0.0
happiness : {'Successes': 0, 'Occured': 1023} Accuracy:  0.0
sadness : {'Successes': 0, 'Occured': 685} Accuracy:  0.0
surprise : {'Successes': 0, 'Occured': 442} Accuracy:  0.0
neutral : {'Successes': 718, 'Occured': 718} Accuracy:  1.0
```

Code below;

```
#Test our model's performance
truth = []
predict = []

#Test a batch of 128 test images against the model
for i in range(128):
    a,b = next(testGen)
    predict.append(model.predict(a))
    truth.append(b) 

predict = np.concatenate(predict) #Array of predictions model has made
truth = np.concatenate(truth) #Array of true results

successes = 0
items = []
for i in range(len(classes)):
  items.append({"Successes" : 0, "Occured" : 0})

for i in range(0, len(predict)):
    items[np.argmax(truth[i])]["Occured"] += 1 
    if (np.argmax(predict[i]) == np.argmax(truth[i])):  # If the model's prediction matches the true value
      successes += 1  
      items[np.argmax(truth[i])]["Successes"] += 1


print("Total tests performed: ", len(predict))
print("Total accuracy: ", successes/len(predict))
print()
for i in range(len(classes)):
  print(classes[i], ':', items[i], "Accuracy: ", (items[i]["Successes"]/items[i]["Occured"]))
```

Comment: Fluctuation of loss during training is normal, as you are doing batch gradient descent (i.e. your `batch_size` is smaller than the size of data). You might find this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345990/why-does-the-loss-accuracy-fluctuate-during-the-training-keras-lstm) useful. Other than that, your model seems to be on the right track, just let it train for more number of epohcs/ tweak the hyperparameters.

Comment: I left it training for double the epochs, it steadily improved until plummeting after ~24 epochs. Shown in EDIT 2

Comment: @JacobRolph save checkpoints based on the best accuracy and restore training if your accuracy falls significantly

Comment: It appears the steady increase was just lucky, every time I train it now both accuracies fluctuate wildly between 12-26%, while loss stablises at 1.792. I used code included in EDIT 3 to test predictions and it's only successfully guessing one class.